# Referencing spring bean values from xsd schema

Tags: xml, spring, xslt, xsd

I am trying to write an xml schema xsd that includes validation (patterns for strings, min/max for int etc). I want the restrictions in place for the validation to depend on an external xml config file (spring beans file).

For instance in the beans/config file I have something like the following:

```
....
<bean id=bean1 class="com.example.package.Class1">
     <property name=validation value="[a-zA-Z]">
</bean>
...
```

in my xsd schema I would like to reference the validation property as the pattern to match a string to.

I'd ideally like something like the following:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:simpleType name="elementToValidate">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern ref="bean1/validation" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

but I can't get the imports to work. As far as I've tried, the `import` and `include` tags only allow to extend the schema with other xsd files, not other xml. Using

```
<import resource="path/to/file.xml"/>
```

does not seem to work either.

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to look into other ways around it?
Thanks

---

Edit: Thanks to @helderdarocha for the answer. This has highlighted an additional similar problem. Is there any way of accessing values from the xml to use in validation of the rest of the file? for instance, for

```
<xmlNode>
    <property name="prop1">3</property>
    <property name="prop2">4</property>
</xmlNode>
```

ensuring that prop2 > prop1 or otherwise using the value of prop1 to validate prop2?

Comment: If you want to use something like XPath extraction, you can *generate* your XSD with a simple XSLT stylesheet that extracts those values from the beans.xml file

Comment: You can access any value from the XML (or even other documents) using XSLT. Are you trying to generate validation rules? Perhaps it would be a good idea to post this as a new question (also for more visibility) tagged with xsd and xslt. It might attract some alternative solutions as well. (If you do so, be sure to include the spring source file, showing the headers, and the code, xsl or other, you have so far)

Comment: @helderdarocha Have done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167003/accessing-previous-xml-values-while-validating-the-xml-file-from-generated-schem). Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using XSLT you can generate your XSD, extract selected data from your `beans.xml` file and place them wherever you wish. You could also perform much more additional processing, modify data, etc.

I assume you have a `beans.xml` file like this one:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="bean1" class="com.example.package.Class1">
        <property name="validation" value="[a-zA-Z]"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="bean2" class="com.example.package.Class2">
        <property name="validation" value="[0-9]"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Using the `spring.xml` above as your input source, and the XSLT stylesheet below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    exclude-result-prefixes="spring">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//spring:property"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="spring:property[@name='validation']">
        <xsd:simpleType name="{parent::spring:bean/@id}-validation-rule">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:pattern ref="{@value}" />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You will generate this XSD document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:simpleType name="bean1-validation-rule">
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
         <xsd:pattern ref="[a-zA-Z]"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="bean2-validation-rule">
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
         <xsd:pattern ref="[0-9]"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

See this **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/b4GWVn)** for a live working example.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try and work through it today and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I'm having some issues with this but mainly I think because my requirements have changed. Is there anyway to read in the value from the xml that's being validated? See edit for example.

Comment: Marking as accepted as it answered my question well until I changed it.